# Командная строка не реагирует на .py файлы

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

Добрый день. 
На машине (w7) установлен python 3.5.2:
[image]

В PATH вроде как тоже всё в порядке (?)
[image]

Однако на вызов .py скрипта cmd реагирует так:

С:\ 1.py

C:\

То есть - никак. Реагирует cmd так на скрипт с ошибками, без ошибок, простой, сложный, с выводом, с вводом... Интернет подсказки не дал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В процессе написания вопроса разобралась, в чём дело, решила оставить вопрос - вдруг кому-то будет полезно. На компе был установлен pyCharm, который считался программой по умолчанию для открывания .py файлов, и это всё портило. Стоило поставить python.exe как программу по умолчанию, всё стало работать. Логично, но вчера я до этого не дошла.

Comment: полезно в таких случаях посмотреть на [assoc, ftype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890879/in-python-3-5-when-using-a-argument-list-as-input-to-subprocess-popen-i-cann#comment67893127_39890879) и ["Open with" диалог в проводнике](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890879/in-python-3-5-when-using-a-argument-list-as-input-to-subprocess-popen-i-cann#comment67898494_39890879) (на файловые ассоциации системы в регистре `HKLM\Software\Classes`)

Answer (score 1):

Можно явно указывать, в какой программой открывать скрипты:

```
С:\ python.exe 1.py
```

В этом случае даже если по умолчанию стоит другая программа, открываться всё равно будет в python.exe

Comment: Да, я это тоже нашла позже)  но я всё равно упорно хотела заставить командную строку понимать меня без этого :)